# How to press Ctrl plus w keys three times via SendKeys method in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, browser, tabs, sendkeys

The following code press the **TAB key** three times.  The following code is okey.

```
SendKeys "{TAB 3}", True
```

How to press **Ctrl** plus **w keys** three times?

I have tried the following code but it doesnt work.

```
SendKeys "^w 3", True
```

Please note that **Ctrl** plus **w keys** is using to close Active Web Page.

So I want to close last three web pages.

Comment: `To specify repeating keys, use the form {key number}.` I think the `key` doesn't support key combinations, although the documentation doesn't explicitly mention it. _Microsoft documentation:_

> [SendKeys statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009015)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) . How about `For i=1 To 3: SendKeys "^w", True : Next i`?

Comment: You can't use write the code three times or loop three times?  That doesn't work?

Comment: @Skin You are right. I just want to eliminate the count of code lines.

Comment: @taller You are right. But I have asked how to make `SendKeys "^w 3", True` form works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls. try this

```
SendKeys "^{w 3}", True
```